# Как мне получить id добавленной view за пределами цикла с методом addView

Tags: android

Я добавляю в linearLayout, (находящийся внутри scrollView) view'хи используя layoutInflater:

```
    for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.owner_item, scrollinlayout, false);
        ...
        linearLayout.addView(inflatedView);
   }
```

Как мне получить id добавленной view за пределами данного цикла? Точнее говоря я хочу иметь доступ ко всему списку добавленных вьюх т.е. типа `ArrayList<Integer>` или `ArrayList<View>`, чтобы потом можно было у каждой вью вызывать её методы 
например: `addedView.getBackground().setAlpha(128);`

Спасибо!

Comment: Объявить свой список в области видимости того места, где вы собираетесь после вызывать его

Comment: В целом ваш вопрос наводит на мысль, что вам надо использовать RecyclerView + Adapter с хранилищем. Если не хотите добавлять кучу бойлерплейта попробуйте библиотеки тика такой https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если делать исходя из условия задачи, можно сделать так:

```
for(int i = 0; i< data.linearLayout.getChildCount()-1; i++){
    linearLayout.getChildAt(i).yourMethod();
}
```

Другой вариант (опять же из условия), как вы предложили сами - добавлять все `View` в `ArrayList`: `myViews.add(inflatedView)` и потом так же его находить. Этот вариант лучше, если у вас в `linearLayout` есть другие, не относящиеся к задаче, `View`.

Но самое правильное, как вам сказали в комментах, использовать `RecyclerView`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter .ViewHolder> {
    private List<MyData> dataList;
    private Context ctx; //можно убрать если работа с контекстом в адаптере не нужна

    public MyAdapter (Context ctx, List data) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        dataList = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.owner_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {  
        //производить нужные действия          
        viewHolder.txt.setText(dataList.get(i).getName()); //например такие
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txt;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);    

            txt.setOnClickListener(...);
        }

    }

}
```

Заполнять `RecyclerView` так:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,myDataList));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! О RecyclerView я знаю, просто задача была использовать именно ScrollView и ничего кроме